# cannot start vault container with mysql storage

Tags: mysql, docker, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to start Vault docker container with mysql storage using this command:

```
docker run  --cap-add=IPC_LOCK  -e 'VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG={"storage": {"mysql": {"username":"root", "password":"hello", "database":"vault", "address":"127.0.0.1:3306"}}, "listener": {"tcp":{"address":"127.0.0.1:8200", "tls_disable":"1"}}, "default_lease_ttl": "168h", "max_lease_ttl": "720h"}' -e VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY=true vault server
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Error initializing storage of type mysql: failed to check mysql schema
>   exist: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused

I can connect to mysql using the username and password I am supplying to the previous command.

I also made sure that the mysql is running on the 3306 port

```
[root@jwahba]# netstat -tlpn | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      39552/mysqld
```

I checked out the vault official document ([here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/mysql.html)) but it's not obvious what is wrong in my configuration. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Have you addded certificates to the MySql DB? If so, you should tell Vault to use them to connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect to a db on localhost from a Docker container, but they are on different network stacks. Use `--net="host"` in your `docker run` command; 127.0.0.1 in your docker container will now point to your docker host.

Source: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)